# 3 images in a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add three images in an html website:Two in a row and one below them in the center and also want to keep it mobile compatible. 
Please help me if anyone has a solution for this. I've searched but did not find any solution for compatibility and the images coming in the proper order .

Comment: using bootstrap?

Comment: provide your code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) and `<br>` and use css `text-align` to center the third, and they should all be placed in one `<div>` (at least one).

Comment: you want to put them in a table? first row 2 cells, the second row 1 cell with colspan=2?

Comment: unfortunately, I can only answer adding 2 or 4 images, I've never done 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The best way to do this is to use **bootstrap** classes

[Bootstrap Grid Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Schrodinger-as-a-kitten..png"  style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Schrodinger-as-a-kitten..png"  style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Yoshi-The-Seal-Kitteh.jpg"  style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hoe you are seeking for this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left"><img src=""/></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right"><img src=""/></div>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin: auto"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this , is this what you need ? i have used `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center`

```css
.img_container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.img_container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
.img_container div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
   <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/22/53/heart-1776746_960_720.jpg" alt="image" />
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/22/53/heart-1776746_960_720.jpg" alt="image" />
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/22/53/heart-1776746_960_720.jpg" alt="image" />
   </div>
</div>
```